# Fitting a 2D array with two parameters to another 2D array

Tags: fitting, image

I am trying to fit an array to an image generated from real data. Here is the sample image:

[image: data]

This is a filtered magnetic dipole with some noise thrown in, and now I'm trying to fit my equation for a magnetic dipole to it after applying a Gaussian filter.

```
(* Magnetic Field Equation *)
Bx[m_, x_, y_, z_] := 10^6 (10^-7*m*3*(-1) (z^2 - 2 x^2 + y^2))/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(5/2)

(* Color Scheme *)
ColorRGB := {(RGBColor[0, #, #] &), (RGBColor[#, #, 0] &), (RGBColor[#, 0, #] &)} 

(* Averaging the function *)
Bxa[m_, r_] := 
 GaussianFilter[
  Mean[Table[Bx[m, x, y, z], {z, 0.02, .20, .01}, {y, -1, 1, .065}, {x, -1, 1, .065}]],
  r];

(* adding noise *)
fakex = Bxa[1, 5.25];
FakeNoise = fakex + RandomReal[{Min[fakex]/5, Max[fakex]/5}, Dimensions[fakex]];

(* This is my fake sample data I want to fit to *)
ArrayPlot[FakeNoise, 
   PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> ColorRGB[[1]],ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> All, FrameTicks -> Automatic]
```

That is my entire code for this, and now I want to fit `Bxa[m, r]`, which is essentially just a less noisy version of the plot above, to the fake data plot that I put above, with parameters $m$ and $r$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fitting" another array to it? Since you have such a complicated model without an analytic expression life will be potentially nasty. On the other hand playing with the `Bxa` function over different `r` and `m` it seems the structure is entirely determined by `r` and the heights are entirely determined by `m`. Then you can just look at the peaks on your plot and get `m` and `r` guesses from there.

Comment: @b3m2a1 What I would like to do is just use something like the FindFit function with the noisy array and my `Bxa` and it would spit out values for `m` and `r` that make `Bxa` most suitable to the data.

Comment: Why do you want to fit an image rather than fitting the data directly?